# Can't install Ubuntu, mother board problem i think

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a little big problem.
4-5 months ago, I changed my video card from R7 240 to gtx 970, ok fine, but now i have some problems.

My pc:
FX 6300
motherboard: AsRock 980DE3/U3S3

Some of problems:

1. When I try to install Ubuntu, shows me that loading screen, and then, restart and black screen. and i need to pull the plug and open again because is frozen ( not only this os )
2. When I want to enter in Windows I need to enter in bios and leave ( i don't know the reason but when I don't do this, windows loading and then gray screen)

   I don't think is from video card, I think I should update the bios or buy another mother board.. because I want to install Ubuntu and I can't..

Thanks for helping :)

sorry for my english btw

Comment: Are you changing settings when you enter into the bios and leave? It sounds like you have windows installed in UEFI mode, and ubuntu is stalling in mbr mode. To install in UEFI mode, make sure to boot the ubuntu live session in UEFI mode by setting bios uefi settings to those used by windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS probably contains settings like AHCI mode or "Legacy" mode or other boot options.